# Should I combine PHP with ajax to post data to the server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Imagine the page always refreshes after submitting a comment form. That is annoying since the comments are at not at the top of the page and you always have to scroll to the bottom to see your comment and the other ones.

I thought it would be a lot better to use ajax to submit the form.

**HTML**

```
<form id="com-form" method="post">
    <textarea type="text" name="text" required=""></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
<div id="com-refresh"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#com-form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form      = $(this),
        form_data = form.serialize();
    $.post('/php/comments/add.php', form_data, function(data) {
        $("#com-refresh").append(data);
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'comment.class.php';           //require a class with methods
$text = $_POST['text'];
if($_SESSION['status'] == 'loggedin') {
    if(isset($text)) {
        $comment = new Comment();           //initialize the Comment object
        echo $comment->add_comment($text);  //safe the comment in the database and output it
    } else echo "Your comment is empty.";
} else echo "Please log in to post comments.";
```

I hope the code is understandable.

Do you think it is smart or a bad practice to use ajax to not refresh the page after submitting a form?

How should it be done? Do you have a better idea, a cleaner solution?

Comment: simply you can redirect the file from add.php file to build.php after complete the process using header('location:comments/build.php'); or some other else, so second ajax call was unnecessary.

Comment: ok, I left the second ajax out and redirected to build.php in add.php and in my browser console I get: add.php 302 Moved Temporarily, build.php 403 forbidden.

Comment: Both add.php and build.php files are in same location or different location? and post your header code in add.php

Comment: no, actually they are in a different location.
here is the answer of the header: 
Cache-Control no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Length 0
Content-Type text/html
Date Wed, 30 Apr 2014 10:55:20 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive timeout=4, max=500
Location /php/comments/includes/build.php
Pragma no-cache
Server Apache/2.4

Comment: how about instead of serialize() try using `var text = $("textarea#com-area").val();` and `data: { post_data: text },` ?

Comment: the main problem I focus on now is not the the comment is added, but that the div does refresh. so I don't care if the comment is not successfully added yet. it would be nice if it's possible to reinclude the comment section

Comment: use this header('location:comments/build.php'); remove / from the header, if / added this will indicate the absolute path

Comment: but it was the correct absolute path, wasn't it?

Comment: i get "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the php code. I have rewritten the functions that generate the comments in OOP style which helped a lot. I edited the post know so it can be useful in the future.

**To make it short:**

- Use ajax! Your website's user experience will be a lot better, because you are able to provide live updates, etc.
- It is recommendable to use the built-in jQuery function [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to safe data into a "text string in standard URL-encoded notation", that can make your work more simple.
- I know there is a lot of discussions about OOP, but it really helps understanding, organizing and maintaining your code more easily

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) { 
    $(".mydiv").html(xhr.responseText);     
});
```

having your php file print what ever html you want to replace.

further reading: [ajaxSuccess](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)

example of what might be your solution

form file:

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea type="text" name="comment" id="com-area"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="com-submit"/>
</form>
<div id="com-refresh">
    <?php require_once "comments/build.php"; ?>
</div>
$(function() {
    $(".cmtx_form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var text = $(".cmtx_textarea_field").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'comments/add.php?ajaxCall=true',
            cache: false,
            data: { comment: text }
        });
     });
  });

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) { 
    $("#com-refresh").html(xhr.responseText);     
});
```

your add.php file should look somewhat like so:

```
// ... code code code...
if (isset($_GET['ajaxCall']) && $_GET['ajaxCall']) {
    include_once('/path/to/build.php');
}
```

Comment: i get build.php 408 Request Timeout

Comment: ok i have added the content of the add.php fie now and updated the jquery

Comment: where is your ajaxSuccess function?

Comment: but forget about the first ajax, firstly, i just want to reinclude the build.php file after the form is submitted so the comment section will be built again, it doesnt matter if the comment is successfully added now.

Comment: Try require instead of require_once

Comment: i'm sorry, I dont get it. the form and the ajax script are on the same file? is that file also requires the build.php file?

Comment: not in the same file, but both required on one web page. one file builds the whole comment section: build.php. another file updates the database: actually add.php. the build.php should be reincluded/refreshed after submitting the form. is there a possibility of refreshing a container with jquery ajax???

Comment: Okay, what you should do is:1) on your ajax call add a GET parameter ajaxCall=true. 2) on your add.php ask if $_GET['ajaxCall'] is set and true and if so, require build.php there.

Comment: so i also have to change the type of the ajax to 'GET', right?

Comment: Not really no. HTML headers can hold POST and GET requests together. :)

Comment: for me it isn't important now if it's safe and an ajaxCall exists, I just want to know if I can reinclude that file somehow even though the comments didn't change

Comment: so the only thing i still have to do know is to include this response code into the div#div-refresh. i tried it with .ajaxSuccess, but the page just loads and loads... it stays white

Comment: I don't understand what is it you are trying to accomplish, please provide code with some explanations.

Comment: ok, I updated the stuff above. I have written success: function now to try if it works. I get the correct result as an answer from the file (html code for the whole comment section)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51748/discussion-between-user3389375-and-user3540688)

Answer (score 0):

simply you can redirect the file from `add.php` to `build.php` after complete the process using `header('location:comments/build.php');` or some other else, so second ajax call was unnecessary.

Comment: ok, I left the second ajax out and redirected to build.php in add.php and in my browser console I get: add.php 302 Moved Temporarily, build.php 403 forbidden.